# What's wrong with my count characters, words, lines program?

Tags: c, count, character, line

Trying to write a C program that:

counts the number of characters, words and lines read from standard input until EOF is reached.
Assume the input is ASCII text of any length.
Words are defined as contiguous sequences of letters (a through z, A through Z) and the apostrophe ( ', value 39 decimal) separated by any character outside these ranges.
Lines are defined as contiguous sequences of characters separated by newline characters ('\n').
Characters beyond the final newline character will not be included in the line count.

I have written the following, which works fine to count the characters, but does not count any of the words or lines. I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned long int countchar=0;
    unsigned long int word=0;
    unsigned long int line=0;

    int c;

    while (((c=getchar())!=EOF)) {

        countchar++;

        if ((c>='A' && c<= 'Z') || (c>='a' && c<= 'z') || (c==39)) {    
            word++;
        }

        else if (c=='\n') {
            line++;
        }
    }

    printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", countchar, word, line);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You should remove the char. It's a data type in c.

Comment: How will you handle the line-count on a file with a non-POSIX file-ending? (e.g. no `'\n'` at the end) Won't your line count be short by 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are counting each letter in a word as a word.
It should work to change it to check that it isn't any of the letters in words and remove the else.
You might need to add some extra checks so that you only increase words if the last letter was in a word.

```
if (!((c>='A' && c<= 'Z') || (c>='a' && c<= 'z') || (c==39)) {
    word++;
}
if (c=='\n') {
    line++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

char is a reserved word.  You can't name a variable that.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((c=getchar()!=EOF)) {
```

should be

```
while (((c=getchar())!=EOF)) {
```

because otherwise it's interpreted as

```
while ((c=(getchar())!=EOF))) {
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I changed it now. That made it register the words and lines But for some reason the words are not getting counted correctly. For example, if the input was "testing the program" it will print 20 for characters, 17 for words, and 1 for line. Why is it counting words as 17?